# Soviet Optimization books

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation

I am aware of an answer on Soviet math books here: [Soviet Russian mathematics books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856980/soviet-russian-mathematical-books) and the book by Boris Polyak on non linear optimization. I am also aware of a few books by Kantorovich which I do not have.
I am looking for more recommendations on Soviet optimization books, with English translations. There should be plenty, considering linear programming orignated there in the optimal control. Please do not give an argument stating which books are better American or Soviet. I am not interested in that.

Comment: Have you read Yaglom book for olympiad competition? this book has dozen inequality problems but classical or dated. I own about 4 new books in modern non linear inequalities that are as hard as IMO or MO of several countries but they are not in English.

Comment: @Ganymede nope I haven't but I just looked it up on Amazon. It is actually a bit far from my area and question - I am looking for books dealing with optimization. Such as Linear Programming, Integer Programming etc.